# Why some tags I can not edit them with exiftool

Tags: metadata, exiftool

With exiftool I could not edit some tags like the result after when I put  this line

```
exiftool logo.jpg -"Photoshop Quality"=""
```

I get this message

```
Warning: Sorry, Photoshop is not writable
Nothing to do.
```

My question . why ? how can i fix this problem ? . also I tried this line

```
exiftool logo.jpg -all=""
```

all of tags are removed exception of some like  .  . . .

  File Size

  File Type

So at the first did not edit . But in the second code worked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Photoshop Quality" is not the name of a tag, it is the description.  Make sure you use the command in [exiftool FAQ #2](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q2) to figure out the correct name to process.  You can also look at the [Photoshop Tag page](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/Photoshop.html) to see more info on the Photoshop tags.

The second command will remove all embedded tags in the file, but some tags are actually properties of the file, not embedded information.  `FileSize`, for example, is the actual size of the file as reported by the underlying OS.  `FileType` is the type of the file.  These items can't just be changed on a whim, nor can they be removed.